# How do I save an IP address in a variable?

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error when I use a host Ip in a server I am trying to set up. This has never happened before.

```
# Host Credentials
host = '192.068.0.3'
port = '4445'
```

I am met with this error, right at the .068:

```
invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 12)pylint(syntax-error)
```

Really, how can this be? I'm using Visual Studio Code as my text editor.

Comment: you should show the full error (its probably an issue with a preceeding line missing a quote)

Comment: same thing copy-pasted, works fine for me. use as raw string ```host = r'192.068.0.3'``` in case you are sure, the problem is in same line.